# Spatial clustering vs sampling

Tags: clustering, sampling

I have a dataset with `100` millions Point (lat/lon).

I have started by using GeoHash clustering (applied dynamically by Elasticsearch regarding the user zoom level).

I end up with something like that:

[image: Spatial Clustering]

Clustering is triggered when a certain threshold is reached (when number of points to plot on the map is too big, like 10000 points).

However, in my real-world app, points on the right have many colors (and not only blue) to figure out what kind of data it is.

The problem is that with clustering (triggered on zoom out), I end up only with circles, so it is difficult to present to a user on my web portal the dataset richness.

What it seems interesting with sampling, is that it preserves real point, that is displayed to the user, AND it also allows to reduce down the number of points regarding different level of zoom chosen,

As I'm in situation that I can precompute quickly everything needed statically, my approach with sampling would be:

1. Assign a bin/area to each point (with H3)
2. Select randomly N point per each bin/area (or a most sophisticated custom algorithm that preserve at most the features of data)
3. Do the same for multiples level of zoom

The approach is static and not dynamic (as default Elasticsearch clustering approach), but it may help to avoid triggering clustering most of time, if sampling preserve data features enough

Do you think my approach makes sense?

Comment: Google picks a sample of locations best fitting your many terabytes of personalized online history. Ordered by highest estimated direct or indirect ad revenue...or something equally sinister ,) So the difference to clustering is contextual bias.

Comment: The Google Maps example is just to illustrate the fact that sampling may be interesting over clustering, because it has the advantage to reflect real datapoint. What are your though about sampling/binning over clustering ? Thank you